# Characterization of Subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, mobius-transformation

I consider the Möbius transformations with fixed points $0$ and $1$ and determinant $1$. This gives effectively matrices of the form
$$A_{\tau}:=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\tau} & 0 \\ \frac{1}{\tau}-\tau & \tau\end{pmatrix}$$
for some complex $\tau\neq 0$. Now, the set $\Gamma:=\lbrace A_{\tau}| \tau\in\mathbb{C}\backslash\lbrace 0\rbrace\rbrace$ induces a subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ and because $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is a Lie group (with $\mathrm{dim}_{\mathbb{C}} SL(2,\mathbb{C}) = 3$), I think that $\Gamma$ can be seen as a submanifold with complex dimension $1$ in the manifold of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$.

But there should be more to say about it, due to the specific form of the matrices $A_{\tau}$. But I am a bit lost here. I try to find a characterization of $\Gamma$ which  as complete as possible and so all ideas are welcome. Complete proofs are not necessary, I will try to do them myself. Literature recommendations are also highly appreciate. Does the subgroup induced by $\Gamma$ maybe have a specific name?

Comment: Hint: Consider instead the subgroup $T$ fixing $0$ and $\infty$. Your subgroup will be conjugate to this one, but $T$ is much easier to analyze.

Comment: Typically these groups are called one parameter subgroups.

Comment: @MoisheKohan But this conjugate subgroup $T$ acts trivially on $\mathbb{C}$ having the general form $\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\tau} & 0 \\ 0 & \tau \end{pmatrix}$. It is less complex in its form, that is true. Do you mean, it is easier to analyze as a subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ in the Lie group context?

Comment: That's right. The question is what else would you like to know about it?

Comment: Its geometric properties as a Riemann manifold, its "shape" in $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$,... How would I for example visualize the conjugate group $T$?

Comment: This is too vague. Try to formulate a precise question.

Comment: Is $T$ a connected submanifold of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ and what does this imply for $\Gamma$? That would be the first question. I am not used to the techniques/arguments which are necessary...

Comment: It is a closed connected complex Lie subgroup of complex dimension 1; in particular, it is abelian. In the language of algebraic groups, it is called a **maximal torus** of $SL(2, C)$. My suggestion is to at least browse a textbook on Lie groups.

Comment: A maximal torus is in particular isomorphic to the flat torus, or am I misunderstanding this page here? https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Maximal_torus